# Is it possible to use default interface implementation in Android < API 24?

Tags: java, android

Android Studio 2.3.3, Java 8

I create Android app for Android 4.0+

In my **app/build.gradle**:

```
...
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 26
```

I want to use default interface implementation (from Java 8).
So I create the tnext class:

```
public interface DefaultCallback {

    public default void onResponse(Call<T> var1, Response<T> var2) {

    }
}
```

but I get compile error:

*Default method required API level 24 (current min is 15)*

So the question is:

Can I use deafult interface implementation on Android < API 24?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depending on what your minSdk version is you may need to add the following to your app's or module's build.gradle file:

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features for more details

Comment: Yes, on Android Studio 3.0 with "sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8" - it's work!!!

Comment: There is no constraint on a minSdk anymore for language-features.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Default methods require API level 24.

From https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#supported-features:

> Android does not support all Java 8 language features. However, the
>   following features are available when developing apps targeting
>   Android 7.0 (API level 24):
>
> - Default and static interface methods
> - Lambda expressions (also
>     available on API level 23 and lower)
> - Repeatable annotations
> - Method References (also available on API level 23 and lower)
> - Type Annotations
>     (also available on API level 23 and lower)

Comment: Maybe has external libs that allow use interface default implementation in  android < 24?

Comment: This page now redirects to a page that lists it as a supported feature.

Comment: Link point to the old "jack" compiler. Using new "default toolchain" you are able to use "Default and static interface methods"  with any version of android min sdk.